# C++ Вывод из консоли в txt

Tags: c++, консоль

я хочу написать программу,которая определяет технические характеристики компьютера.Вот собственно код программы:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<TCHAR.H>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi.lib")

using namespace std;

void info()
{
//Определяем Device Name с "About Pc"
TCHAR Compname[128];
DWORD namesize = 128;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
if (GetComputerName(Compname, &namesize))
    std::wcout << "Device name: " << "\t" << Compname << endl;
else
    std::wcout << "\t" << "Name computer - Error!!!" << endl << endl;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем Device Name с "About Pc"
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Определяем имя юзера Windows
char username[UNLEN + 1]{};
DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
::GetUserNameA(username, &username_len);
std::wcout << "User profile:   " << username << endl;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем имя юзера Windows
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Определяем текущую раскладку пользователя
int i = (int)GetKeyboardLayout(GetCurrentThreadId());
wchar_t lang[1024];
LCID lcid = MAKELCID(i, SORT_DEFAULT);
GetLocaleInfoW(lcid, LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, lang, 1024);
std::wcout << "Keyboard: " << lang << endl;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем текущую раскладку пользователя
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Определяем системную информацию
SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo;
GetSystemInfo(&lpSystemInfo);
std::wcout << "System Info:  " << endl << endl;
{
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask << " - Active Processor Mask" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwPageSize << " - Page Size" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwAllocationGranularity << " - Allocation Granularity" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors << " - Number Of Processors" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwOemId << " - Oem Id" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.dwProcessorType << " - Processor Type" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress << " - Maximum Application Address" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress << " - Minimum Application Address" << endl;
    std::wcout << "\t" << lpSystemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture << " - Processor Architecture" << endl << endl;
}
TCHAR dir[30];
if (GetWindowsDirectory(dir, 30) == 1)
    std::wcout << "Error dir" << endl;
else
    std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем системную информацию
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Определяем директорию Windows и какие есть носители информации(жесткие диски,флешки и т.п)
std::wcout << "Windows Directory: " << dir << endl << endl;
char buf[26];
GetLogicalDriveStringsA(sizeof(buf), buf);
const char* DRF[] = { "Unknown" , "Invalid path",
    "Removable", "Fixed" , "Network drive","CD-ROM", "RAM disk" };
for (char* s = buf; *s; s += strlen(s) + 1)
    std::wcout << s << "  " << DRF[GetDriveTypeA(s)] << endl;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем директорию Windows и какие есть носители информации(жесткие диски,флешки и т.п)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   //Определяем название видеокарты(адаптеры)
IDXGIFactory1* pFactory;
HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)(&pFactory));
int AdapterNumber = 0;
IDXGIAdapter1* Adapter;
cout << "Adapters:" << endl;
while (pFactory->EnumAdapters1(AdapterNumber++, &Adapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 Desc;
    Adapter->GetDesc1(&Desc);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", Desc.Description);
    Adapter->Release();
}
pFactory->Release();
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем название видеокарты(адаптеры)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Определяем размер экрана
BOOL desktopSizeX;
BOOL desktopSizeY;
desktopSizeX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
desktopSizeY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
std::wcout << "Monitor Size: " << desktopSizeX << "x" << desktopSizeY << endl;
std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
//Определяем размер экрана
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
system("pause");
}
```

ВОПРОС к Вам Господа: Как по окончанию программы мне автоматически записать(без ввода чего либо в консоль) то,что выводится в консоли в ТАКОМ ЖЕ виде как оно выглядит,в файл .txt,который необходимо создать на рабочем столе,например.Заранее благодарю за внимание и помощь!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Comment: Здесь решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

Comment: Спасибо огромное,что тыкнули)Пример со stackoverflow помог!

Answer (score 0):

Так пишите сразу и в консоль и в txt. Создайте свою функцию, куда будете передавать указатели на потоки вывода, куда  надо писать и то, что надо писать, а функция пусть уже пишет везде одно и то же.